# Matlab simple loop

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to create a simple loop that will exit if it has to iterate more than 25 times.

Here is my attempt:

```
for x = 1 : size(adj, 1)   

    if x > 25
        break
    end

    % some code here for printing but I've omitted it since not relevant

end
```

Sorry I've tried googling it and I don't know why it won't work.

Comment: i don't know matlab but I don't see where you are incrementing a counter

Comment: @DanBeaulieu from an example I think matlab automatically increments x at the "end" of the loop

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: here's a video on looping in matlab: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VKkuIRx-e0

Comment: What is the variable adj exactly?

Comment: "won't work" = errors, doesn't do what you expect?  At first glance, this should work (`x` will be 26 at break but the code after that `if` loop shouldn't run).

Comment: @DanBeaulieu yes, contrary to C in Matlab the increment is done automatically  for you.
@Steven , as @freude suggested it would help if you would say what `adj` is in your code

Comment: Works for me.  Edit your example so that it is runnable and demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the limit is `25`, you can just change the loop conditions:

```
for x=1:25
% your code here
```

Alternatively, you could define your upper limit **before** calling the loop:

```
my_limit = min(25,size(adj,1));
for x = 1:my_limit
% your code here
```

Hope this helps!